# What might cause "F/tombstoned: failed to open directory: /data/anr: Permission denied"?

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, permission-denied

Building a Flutter application to an emulator recently started throwing this message:

`F/tombstoned: failed to open directory: /data/anr: Permission denied`

It comes every few seconds, indefinetly:

[image: Screengrab of message]

I've tried reinstalling/updating both Flutter and Visual Studio Code to no avail, and I can't seem to find any information regarding what might cause it.

It works without issue running on a physical device.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't really sound like it has something to do with flutter, have you tried running it on a different device/simulator/emulator?

Comment: I tried it on my phone now and it works without issue. Good catch!